# How to create a simple box that contains another box in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-pic, box, venn-diagrams

I would like to create something like,

[image]

or

[image]

Does anyone know how to create these simple diagrams?

Note: corner need not be rounded. Text need not be Hello World. Edge color need not to be blue.

Comment: tcolorbox is the way forward

Comment: please have a look at the answer if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pg 110 of the manual -- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black,colback=white,}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        
        \tcbox[on line, size=fbox]{Hello}       \hfill    World
    
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                
                \tcbox[on line, size=fbox]{Hello}       \hspace{4cm}    World
                
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
            
            \tcbox[on line, size=fbox]{Hello}        World
            
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{document}
```

If you want to change the inner box simply enter options as below

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
 \tcbox[on line, colframe=red!50!black, colback=yellow!50!green, ]
                 {Hello}\hspace{4cm} World
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Another way is to use the sidebyside option in tcolorbox--results are the same

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    %outer box options
     \tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,righthand 
     width=4cm,sidebyside,sidebyside gap=6mm,lower separated=false}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside align=center seam]
     %inner box options
        \tcbox[on line, colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!50!, ]{Hello}
        \tcblower World
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

**Putting everything in beamer environment**

```
\documentclass[]{beamer} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black,colback=white,}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        
        \tcbox[on line, colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!50!green, ] 
            {Hello}        \hspace{4cm}     World
    
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                
                \tcbox[on line, size=fbox]{Hello}       \hspace{4cm}    World
                
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
            
            \tcbox[on line, size=fbox]{Hello}        World
            
            
            
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]
        \tcbox[on line]{Hello}  \tcbox[ on line, enhanced, 
     skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw, colframe=red]{World}
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.I will take a look!

Comment: a lot of -1 coming my way but no explanation